# Firebase Angular 2 - Way to prevent list of conversations observables refreshing for every client that is subscribed

Tags: angular, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, ionic2

So I'm utilizing Angular 2/Firebase observables for creating a list of conversations that a user is part of. However, I've noticed that if any of the conversations get updated in the `/conversations` endpoint, even if the user isn't part of that conversation, the UI for their conversation list shows a refresh.

Basically, I'm trying to figure out if that's due to all of the conversations are within a single tree or if there's something in my code that's causing that to happen.

Either way, here's an example of how my conversations tree is designed:

**/conversations**

```
{
  "-KfOStwLKzERlOxIaU7V" : {
    "created_at" : "2017-03-16T23:32:59.830Z",
    "creator_id" : "dsfsdg12123RSDvsfbgrgwef",
    "last_message" : "helllooo",
    "last_message_author_id" : "dsfsdg12123RSDvsfbgrgwef",
    "last_updated" : "2017-03-16T23:46:05.645Z",
    "type" : "individual",
    "users" : {
      "dsfsdg12123RSDvsfbgrgwef" : true,
      "gHRdadg567AAA344cGHJsaw1" : true
    }
  }
}
```

**/users/{userID}/conversations**

```
{
   "convoId1": true,
   "convoId2": true
}
```

Here is the code that gets the conversations for a particular user

```
    getConvosForUser(userId) {

        return this._af.database
          .object(`/social/users/${userId}/conversations`)

          // Switch to the joined observable
          .switchMap((conversations) => {

            // Delete the properties that will throw errors when requesting
            // the convo keys
            delete conversations['$key'];
            delete conversations['$exists'];
            delete conversations['$value'];

            // Get an array of keys from the object returned from Firebase
            let convoKeys = Object.keys(conversations);
            let convosObj = conversations;

            if(convoKeys.length > 0) {
              return Observable.combineLatest(
                convoKeys.map((convoKey) => this._af.database
                  .object(`/social/conversations/${convoKey}`)
                ),
                (...conversations) => {

                  // Determine if the user is connected to the owner
                  convoKeys.forEach(key => {
                    conversations.forEach(conversation => {
                      if(conversation.$key === key) {
                          conversation['is_connected_to_owner'] = convosObj[key];
                      }
                    })
                  })

                  // Then return the aggregated conversation data
                  return conversations;
                }
              );
            // Otherwise, just return an empty observable
            } else {
              return Observable.of([]);
            }
          });
      }

getUsersForConversations(conversations) {

    if(conversations.length > 0) {

      // Since there are conversations, let's iterate
      // over them and determine which to show.
      conversations.forEach((conversation, index) => {
        // Get user out of local storage
        this.storage.get('user').then(user => {

          let userKeys = [];
          // Get the user IDs associated with this conversation
          if(conversation.users) {
            userKeys = Object.keys(conversation.users).filter(key => {
              return key !== user.id;
            });
          }

          let usersArr = [];

          let obsUsers = Observable
            .from(userKeys)
            .flatMap(key => {
              return Observable.combineLatest(
                Observable.of(key),
                this._af.database.object(`/social/conversations_last_deleted/${conversation.$key}/${user.id}`)
                  .filter((lastDeleted) => {
                    let convoLastUpdated = +(new Date(conversation.last_updated));

                    if((lastDeleted && lastDeleted.$value === null) ||
                      (lastDeleted && lastDeleted.last_deleted && (convoLastUpdated >= lastDeleted.last_deleted))) {
                      return true;
                    }
                  })
                  .flatMap(lastDeleted => {
                    return this._messages.getMessagesForConvo(conversation.$key, lastDeleted)
                  }),
                (key, messages) => {
                  if (messages.length === 0) {
                    return null;
                  }
                  return key;
                })
            })
            .flatMap(userKey => this._af.database.object(`/social/users/${userKey}`))
            .subscribe((users) => {

              // There is a weird bug with results returning null,
              // so just check to make sure results aren't null and push
              // the user result if it isn't
              if(users.$value !== null) {
                usersArr.push(users);
                conversations[index].users = usersArr;
                this.conversations = conversations;
              }
            });
        });
      });
    } else {
      return Observable.of([]);
    }
  }
```

And then finally the code that pieces the two together:

```
// Get all of the conversations for a user
      this.convosSub = this._messages.getConvosForUser(user.id).subscribe(conversations => {

        this.usersConvosSub = this.getUsersForConversations(conversations);
      });
```

I realize this is a lot of code, but I swear...this conversations piece of my app is easily the most complex piece and I've been battling with it for weeks and weeks. I get a lot of weird behavior with my conversations, so I'm not sure if it's how my trees are structured or my code is bonkers.

Anyway, I greatly appreciate the help in advance!

Comment: There's no (efficient and simple) AngularFire2-based solution to this at the moment. This is one of the reasons I want to refactor the `FirebaseListObservable`. See https://github.com/angular/angularfire2/issues/854#issuecomment-285977773

Comment: So am I kinda stuck on this one for now, then?

Comment: Yep, you are pretty much stuck until AngularFire2 offers some facility for telling you not just that the list has changed, but which item has been changed, added or removed.